# Python - How to check if a key has null value in a JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In a JSON, I want to check and count who has a degree (the highest level one, and what kind) and who hasn't. While counting and checking the Masters, PhDs and such , works, checking if there is null , doesn't.

Part of the JSON

```
  "id": 125428,
  "Degree": "Master",
```

different candidate:

```
  ""id": 125589,
  "Degree": null,
```

different candidate:

```
  "id": 944987,
  "Degree": "PhD"
```

My relevant code is  the following :

```
mastercounter = 0
phdcounter = 0
nodeegreecounter = 0

for candidate in response["person"]:
    if item["Degree"]:
        if item["Degree"]["key"] == "Master":
            mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
        if item["license"]["key"] == "PhD":
            phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
   if item["Degree"] == None: 
       nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
```

The error I'm getting is "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Is it the identation wrong, or the code/my whole logic ?

Comment: Where does "key" come from?

Comment: What do you expect `"PhD"["key"]` to result in?

Comment: You probably need to skip the ```["key"]``` and compare your ```item["Degree"] == "Master" ``` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

What about using if/else?

```
mastercounter = 0
phdcounter = 0
nodeegreecounter = 0

for candidate in response["person"]:
    if item["Degree"]:
        if item["Degree"]["key"] == "Master":
            mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
        if item["license"]["key"] == "PhD":
            phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
    else: 
       nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
```

Comment: Ι didn't think of a simple else! That did it !

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how your JSON is organized. I suspect the response is a sequence of persons. Like this:

```
response = [{"id": "1", "Degree": "Master"}, {"id": "2", "Degree": null}]
```

Therefore you should use:

```
for person in response:
```

you only need one attribute of a person (named "Degree").

Thus, if a person is a sequence of attributes, the code becomes:

```
for person in response:
    if person["Degree"] is None:
        nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
    elif person["Degree"] == "Master":
        mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
    elif person["Degree"] == "PhD":
        phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
```

If your JSON is organized differently, you should explain the JSON structure before asking for advice.

If your JSON looks like this:

```
{"key11": {"id": "1", "Degree": "Master"}, "key12": {"id": "2", "Degree": null}}
```

The code can be:

```
for key in response:
    if response[key]["Degree"] is None:
        nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
    elif response[key]["Degree"] == "Master":
        mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
    elif response[key]["Degree"] == "PhD":
        phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
```

or

```
for key, person in response.items():
    if person["Degree"] is None:
        nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
    elif person["Degree"] == "Master":
        mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
    elif person["Degree"] == "PhD":
        phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Access dict keys correctly.

```
mastercounter = 0
phdcounter = 0
nodeegreecounter = 0

for candidate in response["person"]:
    if item["Degree"]:
        if item["Degree"] == "Master":
            mastercounter = mastercounter + 1
        if item["Degree"] == "PhD":
            phdcounter = phdcounter + 1
    else: 
       nodegreecounter = nodegreecounter + 1
```

Comment: Why did you vote me down? Just because you were late with your response? :D P.S. please fix misprints in your code.

Comment: @tkrishtop I didn't vote you down. Made your vote neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer a below URL for all details for your question and answer:

https://www.calhoun.io/how-to-determine-if-a-json-key-has-been-set-to-null-or-not-provided/

Hope it's useful..

Thank you..Enjoy coding.

Comment: That URL links to an article that uses Go, not python.